# iOS certificate import

Tags: ios, xcode, client-certificates

is it possible to import a certificate (p12 or pfx file) programmatically from bundle to the Keychain? I would like to use those certificates in Safari and in my application as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to import the individual cryptographic objects (keys, passwords, certificates and identities) from a p12 or pfx file into the key chain. If you perform this from your app, the imported objects in the key chain are however only "visible" in the application which imported it.

Since your question is too broad to suggest a crisp answer, here are two links which may help:

Apple documentation: [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/certkeytrustprogguide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html)

Apple Tech-Note: [Making Certificates and Keys Available To Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1745/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011636)

Comment: Do you have any Swift sample code for taking a pfx file from the bundle and installing it into the keychain?

Comment: @mathlete p12 and pfx files are both PKCS #12 files - you can use them interchangeable, i.e. you can rename the file "cert.pfx" to "cert.p12". Then you can use [`SecPKCS12Import(_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396915-secpkcs12import) to programmatically retrieve the "items". Actually, you provide  just the content (Data) to this function, which needs to be a PKCS #12 format, filenames don't matter.